# Doctrine Mapping 2 Objects with 1 table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, ddd-repositories

Given i have 2 classes, User and UserId which look like this:

```
<?php

class UserId {
    /** @var int */
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = (int) $value;
    }
}

class User {
    /** @var UserId */
    private $id;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct(UserId $id, $firstName, $lastName) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }
}
```

## Database:

```
User: 

id : INT PK
firstName: VARCHAR
lastName: VARCHAR
```

Is it possible to tell doctrine to generate me a User with a UserId when calling "find()"?

Comment: Yes. But what have you tried?

Comment: I do no understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Imagine this object: $user = new User(new UserId(5), 'Max', 'Johnson'). I want doctrine to automatically create this object, when i call the "find" method on the UserRepository. @Jeremy I don't even know how to start, since i have nothing found on the internet about this special problem. Mapping 1 object to a table is easy, but 2 objects, no idea.

Comment: @Jeremy Could you give me a tip? You seem to know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, I'll explain further on.

**The simple way**

First I have to say that for this simple use-case, the [answer provided by Andresch Serj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21388560/1237411) should suffice.

Set the `UserId` object using the constructor, get the `UserId` object by lazily instantiating it if it isn't present yet:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var UserId
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @param UserId $userId
     * ...
     */
    public function __construct(UserId $userId /* ... */)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->id     = $userId->getId();
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @return UserId
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        if (!$this->userId) {
            $this->userId = new UserId($this->id);
        }

        return $this->userId;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**The real answer**

In order to manipulate an entity when it's loaded (fetched from the database) you could use Doctrine's `PostLoad` event.

First create a listener that will create a new `UserId` object and set it on the `User` entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class UserListener
{
    /**
     * @param  User               $user
     * @param  LifecycleEventArgs $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function postLoad(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $userId = new UserId($user->getId());
        $user->setUserId($userId);
    }
}
```

Then refactor the `getUserId()` method of `User` to simple return the `UserId` object. Add a `setUserId()` method (it's wise to make sure an already present `UserId` object can't be swapped out). Also note the `@EntityListeners` annotation, which tells Doctrine there's a listener in place for this entity:

```
/**
 * @EntityListeners({"UserListener"})
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @return UserId
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param  UserId $userId
     * @return void
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function setUserId(UserId $userId)
    {
        if ($this->userId) {
            throw new RuntimeException("UsedId already present, you can't swap it!");
        }

        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Finally, in the configuration/bootstrap phase of your application you should register the listener:

```
$listener = new UserListener();
$em->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->register($listener);
```

Now, whenever a `User` entity is loaded by Doctrine, a `UserId` object will be inserted into it. This setup is very useful for more advanced use-cases than the one you described.

You can read more about this [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload) and [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-resolver).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need your User Object to be able to deliver the UserID Object you could add it as a private attribute and add a public getter:

```
private $userIdObject;

public function __construct(UserId $id, $firstName, $lastName) 
{
  $this->id = $id; = $id->id;
  $this->userIdObject = $id;
  $this->firstName = $firstName;
  $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

public function getUserId()
{
  return $this->userIdObject();
}
```

It would really help to know why you need this.
What i am saying is: Doctrine is a presentation of your Database. If you want to store the id as an integer, there is no need to have it as an object. 
If you need an Object to do certain things with the id (*generate it, manipulate it ...*) you can have a getter in your user object that generates said object for you.

```
public function getUserId()
{
  return new UserId($this->id);
}
```

Or you could have all those needed methods for manipulating your UserId in a Helper Class or Service.

Comment: Well its the approach from Domain Driven Design. I start reading DDD books and there its kind of standard to have a UserId class. Not 100% sure why (i believe encapsulation and reusablility).

Comment: The reusability issue makes sense in a way. I just really dislike bloated Models and prefer Repositories to have more logiuc instead.